# How to show only the last ajax request result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Total up the amount of the ajax request and show the ajax response when it is the last ajax response.

In other words, how to use only the response of last sent ajax request.

```
var req=0;
function ajaxReq(){
    req++; /total up the amount of request/
    $.ajax({
        url: "result.php",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if(req==1){ /show the response when this is the last request/
                $("#response-element").html(response);
            }
            req--; /Subtract when every success ajax response/
        }
    });
}
```

I using this on viewing messages detail
if the user clicked few threads before the response show out it will show the previous thread detail before the current selected thread detail shown out

Any better solution would be nice for sharing

Comment: Hey Leo, can you help us understand your use case?  If you only want the last response, what is the purpose behind making the previous ajax calls?

Comment: I already updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should decrement as soon as you send request.

```
var req=""; // should be a number
function ajaxReq(){
    req++; /total up the amount of request/
    $.ajax({
        url: "result.php",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            if (req > 1) req -= 1;
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(req==1){ /show the response when this is the last request/
                $("#response-element").html(response);
                req -= 1;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D was wondering if there is any better solution for this :D will improve it

Comment: There is a cleaner way using async.js but that would be overkill.

Comment: Hi, I had tried yours, but the response is not showing..I think is because of the decrement after sending request, the amount would be 0 so it's not gonna show the response

Answer (score 1):

You are more or less on the right lines. This is the only way you can avoid the callbacks of previous calls. You will have to associate an ID with each request and then check if the ID of the request is the last sent request.

```
var sentReqCount = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    sentReqCount++;
    ajaxReq(sentReqCount);
}, 100);

function ajaxReq(thisReqId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "result.php",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (thisReqId === sentReqCount) {
                $("#response-element").html(response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: by this way, can you pass parameter to the function when onclick event??

Comment: example , pass the parameter like onClick="viewTrip('id','value')", the id and value needed to get the messages

Comment: You can! But how is it related to this question?

Comment: Yes yes, It could be much helps